Expo App works fine on development mode but crashes on apk build
This is a snippet of my app.js and I am using the latest versions of the packages
I tried to fix all of the build logs but the same problems occurs, the app works like a charm in expo go app but when building the app as .APK it crashes after login screen or some times give me white screen, so I am not able to access the homeTabs
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import i18n from './src/locales/i18n';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Register from './src/screens/Register';
import ForgotPassword from './src/screens/ForgotPassword';
import SplashScreenComponent from './src/screens/SplashScreen';
import Authority from './src/screens/Authority';
import Profile from './src/screens/Profile';
import Services from './src/screens/Services';
import ServiceDetails from './src/screens/ServiceDetails';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import NotificationsScreen from './src/screens/NotificationsScreen'; 
import BookingsScreen from './src/screens/BookingsScreen';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'; 

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'; 
          } else if (route.name === 'Notifications') {
            iconName = focused ? 'notifications' : 'notifications-outline'; 
          } else if (route.name === 'My Bookings') {
            iconName = focused ? 'calendar' : 'calendar-outline'; 
          } else if (route.name === 'Menu') {
            iconName = focused ? 'menu' : 'menu-outline'; 
          }

          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        headerShown: false
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="My Bookings" component={BookingsScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}


export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isSplashVisible, setSplashVisible] = useState(true);

  const loadFonts = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      GESSTwoBold: require('./assets/fonts/GE_SS_Two_Bold.otf'),
      GESSTwoLight: require('./assets/fonts/GE_SS_Two_Light.otf'),
      GESSTwoMedium: require('./assets/fonts/GE_SS_Two_Medium.otf'),
      STCFont: require('./assets/fonts/stc.otf'),
    });
    setFontsLoaded(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFonts();
  }, []);

  const onAnimationEnd = () => {
    setSplashVisible(false);
  };

  if (!fontsLoaded || isSplashVisible) {
    return <SplashScreenComponent onAnimationEnd={onAnimationEnd} />;
  }

  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName="login">
          <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="register" component={Register} />
          <Stack.Screen name="forgetPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Stack.Screen name="TabNav" component={HomeTabs} options={{ gestureEnabled: false }} /> 
          <Stack.Screen name="Authority" component={Authority} />
          <Stack.Screen name="profile" component={Profile} />
          <Stack.Screen name="services" component={Services} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ServiceDetails" component={ServiceDetails} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}

